# SDL_GetDisplayDPI doesn't work on android

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to get the DPI of the display by calling SDL_GetDisplayDPI, and it doesn't work both on my Nook Color (with CyanogenMod) and Galaxy S5 (with the default version of Android). SDL_GetError says "That operaion is not supported". Is there a different way to find out DPI with SDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer can be found in this thread:
https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/an-issue-with-sdl-getdisplaydpi-on-android/23312

"It looks like GetDisplayDPI is only implemented on Windows, macOS, and X11 currently.

Looking at the Android docs a bit, 160 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; would give a DPI based on the UI scale factor."